# Laravel 5 error can't create new models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model, eloquent

For some reason I get this error. Using my new model logospinner.php.
I't is located in a app/models, all the old models are working but not this new one.

```
FatalErrorException in Handler.php line 25:
Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App\Exceptions\Handler::report() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/smr/vendor/compiled.php on line 1817 and defined in /home/vagrant/Code/smr/app/Exceptions/Handler.php:25
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/Code/smr/vendor/compiled.php(1817): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Error))
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Error))
#2 {main}
thrown
```

Here is the call in the controller.

```
use Logospinner;    
public function logospinner() {
       $data = Logospinner::get();
}
```

And here is the model

```
<?php namespace App;

class Logospinner extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'logospinner';
    protected $guarded = array("id");
    protected $hidden = array();

}
```

Comment: Is it php 7 version?

Comment: Have you added your model to aliases in app.php?

Comment: @b0ne all the other models are also stored there so it is added. It's when i create new models

Comment: @GONG It's php 7 yes

Comment: PHP 7 is not supported for Laravel 5.0 See here https://laravel.com/docs/5.0#server-requirements

Comment: try this namespace App/Models in your new  models

Comment: @b0ne yeah but why does the old models work, when they are structured in the exact same way? Is there anything that I have misssed setting up the new model?

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg you need to update your laravel to 5.1 to use it with 7.*. Or downgrade your php to 5.6

Comment: @GONG I refer you to my previous comment

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg old works because they dont have any errors. I think its an error occurs in new model. So Laravel trying to throw it and cant

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg i think you need to use your model like so `use App\Logospinner`. Because your controller have different namespace, so it will search for `App\Http\Controllers\Logospinner` at now

Comment: You could either do what @GONG said or add an alias for that model in app.php, and then you could use it as `use Logospinner;`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
When a new model is created, a path must be added to

```
\vendor\composer\autoload_classmap.php:

return array(
    'Logospinner' => $baseDir . '/app/Models/logospinner.php',
}
```

Comment: Not correct, try to read upgrade guide from 4.2 to 5.0 https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0

Comment: @GONG Is right you just forgot to namespace your new model properly after moving it to a different directory.